# Add additional claims (such as roles) to JWT retrieved from external providers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core Web API (No UI) that are accepting token retrieved from multiple external identity providers (let's say Google, Facebook, etc).

I also have a Database to check user-role for example

```
username                 | role  
------------------------------------
anderson.silva@gmail.com | superuser
billy.gates@hotmail.com  | user
```

The problem with this is that the claims retrieved from these external identity provider doesn't have this information, so I ended up doing something like this in my method

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string id)
        {
            var role = await _uow.User.GetRoleByUsername(_username);

            if (role != "superuser") return Unauthorized();

            var product = await _uow.Product.GetByIdAsync(id);
            var result = _mapper.Map<ProductDTO>(product);
            return Ok(result);
        }
```

instead of

```
        [Authorize(Roles = "superuser")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string id)
        {
            var product = await _uow.Product.GetByIdAsync(id);
            var result = _mapper.Map<ProductDTO>(product);
            return Ok(result);
        }
```

So is it possible to add additional claim to the token so I don't need to check the role in every method? I've looked around StackOverflow and CMIIW but it seems most of the similar question is a web-based so they can add the claims after login and persist it in the cookie, but mine is just a web-api without any UI and the token is coming from multiple external IdP which I have no control of.

Any response will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

As the very first requirement of JWT Token is prevent other to tampered with it, so the answer is no, you cannot do things like modify the JWT Token.

Explained in detail:

What you mentioning can be refer to Oauth Authorization code flow, which in this case will be trust third party identity provider such as google, facebook,...

And to make it right, using your own application Role, which all third party identity provider out there unaware about... is to make your own identity server.

In .net eco system now, some widely use was:

- Using Identity server 4 if you alright with .net core 3.1 as it's free, and open source.
- If the cost was fine for you, then [this](https://duendesoftware.com/) basically is the Identity server paid version.
- OpenIdDict is the complete free plan as the good old days of Identity Server 4.

You can implement your own using JWT token as well as session approach, just convert from third party Jwt Token to your own.

In the sake of simplicity if you need them real quick, you can create an attribute and move your authorization logic there

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class ApplicationAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        // Implement your own authorization logic here!!!
    }
}
```

Then use it in the controller like this

```
[ApplicationAuthorize]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
}
```